# What's wrong with my house plant? (Chamaedorea)

Tags: diagnosis, indoors, palm

I should start with the fact that I know next to nothing about plants and plant care, but I'm keen to learn and keep my plants alive!

I have two indoor palm type plants, one has been doing absolutely fine and is twice the size as when I bought it, the other though has just been slowly dieing over the time I've had it, which is probably about a year.

Here's a pic of when I got it:

[image]

And here's a sorry looking pic of it now:

[image]

I don't really know what's wrong or how to save it?

The care instructions said it doesn't like direct sunlight, so I keep it further in the room away from the window. I water it when the soil gets dry. It was a bit waterlogged at one point and I fixed that but not sure if that's what caused this. There was a lot of dead leaves so I removed them hence why its now much smaller. I've just noticed its a bit dry so will give it some water.

Hoping I can save what's left and bring it back to its former glory?

**Edit:** managed to find the store I bought it from to get the id, it's a "Chamaedorea" [The Little Botanical](https://thelittlebotanical.com/product/chamaedorea/)

Answer (score 1):

There are many different types of Chamaedorea. Some have single stems, but yours is one of the multi-stem varieties. Perhaps Chamaedorea seifrizii.

All Chamaedorea like bright shade, growing naturally under a canopy of trees. The closer you can get to that, the happier your palm.

Looks like it could use some nutrition. Maybe some palm fertilizer and seaweed spray.

Soil should probably never get dry, but not be sopping wet either.

Palms are generally slow to react, so changes can take a while to show up.